# .ts included stream links gets stop after some time in exoplayer

Tags: android, video, streaming, exoplayer

I have a link that streams.
When I use the link for an IPTV player like Televizo, this plays for an unlimited of time, but when I use this link to my app Exoplayer or my computer's VLC player, this only gets played for some seconds.

The link - http://sample.com:8080/live/789/789/14756.ts

My Code -

```
        MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(videoUrl);
        player.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
        player.prepare();
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

Comment: Cross-posted to Video.SE: https://video.stackexchange.com/q/36965/14571